# How to go from integral to differential form of Gauss' law for magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

In Maxwell's equations, I understand intuitively how: $\oint B \cdot d{a} = 0$ (because there are no monopoles and so equal number of field lines going in and coming out of the surface).

And then using the divergence theorem:

$\int_{V} \left( \nabla \cdot B \right) d\tau = \oint_{S} B \cdot da$

Then $\int_{V} \left( \nabla \cdot B \right) d\tau$ must be = 0.

But then I'm not sure why I can say: $\nabla \cdot B = 0$ and forget about the integral.

Does it just mean that $\nabla \cdot B$ must be zero everywhere?

Comment: $V$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually calculate $\nabla\cdot B$ at a certain point $\vec r$: just choose as the (arbitrary) integration domain a bowl $V_\epsilon(\vec r)$ of radius $\epsilon$. Then let $\epsilon$ tend to zero, so
$$(\nabla\cdot B)(\vec r)\cdot \frac{4}{3}\pi \epsilon^3\to\int_{V_\epsilon(\vec r)}(\nabla\cdot B) d\tau =0$$
Since $\epsilon$ is small but non-zero, you finally get $\nabla\cdot B=0$.